# Allow a group to su to a user without a password in Amazon Linux

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

In Amazon linux on my ec2 server, how do I allow a group of restricted users to su to a specific user.  Also I would like for them not to be prompted for password.  I have a group called 'my-users' and a user called 'app-admin'.  I would like for 'my-users' to be able to su into 'app-admin' and use that user to run programs.  I don't want 'my-users' to have root access.  Do I need to edit the sudoers file?  Do I need to edit the /etc/sudoers.d/cloud-init file?

Comment: Tell the password of app-admin to your trusted users, then they can su to that user anytime.

Comment: I want to users being in the 'my-users' group to be the only requirement to su into the 'app-admin' user.  I want to avoid the use of passwords in this case.

Comment: Then create a suid binary shell file, with owner: app-admin, and group: my-users, other: 000

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.  In your sudoers file, you can put the following entry:

```
%my-users ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/su - app-admin
```

Then you can use the following to login:

```
sudo su - app-admin
```

Note: Be sure to use `sudo visudo` to edit anything sudo related or you could corrupt your sudo privileges.